# How to access same variable in Main() and in thread proc in another class?

Tags: c#, multithreading

If this were C++, I'd use a pointer.  I'm struggling with the C# syntax and new enough to the language that I don't know how to solve this.

This example has a member variables in the class "Program" named "ProgramDat" that I want to access from a thread in another class.  In addition, I want the thread to be able to change that memory location and have Program::Main() see the update as well as Program::Main() change the variable and have the thread see it.

ref doesn't seem to do it.  Is there another construct I could use?

(And I recognize the potential race conditions here.  I left out any synchronization techniques for simplicity of this post.)

Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    static ManualResetEvent ExitEvent;
    static MyThread t;
    static int ProgramDat;

    public static void Main()
    {
        ExitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ProgramDat = 12;      // initialize to some value
        t = new MyThread(ExitEvent, ref ProgramDat);

        Thread.Sleep(1500);     // let MyThread run a bit

        // Main() doesn't see the changes MyThread::RunLoop() made
        Console.WriteLine("Main just before setting to 500, MyFormDat={0}", ProgramDat);
        ProgramDat = 500;       // and this change is not seen in MyThread::RunLoop();
        Console.WriteLine("Main just set MyFormDat={0}", ProgramDat);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Just prior to telling thread to exit, MyFormDat={0}", ProgramDat);
        ExitEvent.Set();
        Thread.Sleep(500);  // wait to let MyThread::RunLoop() finish
        Console.WriteLine("main leaving.  MyFormDat={0}", ProgramDat);
     }
}

public class MyThread
{
    ManualResetEvent e;   
    Thread t;
    int MyThreadDat;

    public MyThread(ManualResetEvent ev, ref int FromProgramDat)
    {
        e = ev; 
        MyThreadDat = FromProgramDat;

        t = new Thread(RunLoop);
        t.Start();
    }

    public void RunLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (e.WaitOne(300) == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("RunLoop leaving!");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("tic.  iFormDat={0}", MyThreadDat);
                MyThreadDat++;      // change it each loop but I can't get Main() to see this change
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: main is a static, your variable will need to be the same.  In the Program class make say ProgramDat public (or internal), In MyThread use MyThreadDat = Program.ProgramDat

Comment: `int` is a value type, assignment always makes a copy of the value.  So changes to MyThreadDat  cannot propagate back.  Consider wrapping it inside a `class`.  You really, really need to read up on threading, this kind of code is going to hurt you badly.  Understanding synchronization is super important.

Answer (score 1):

Most types in .NET are reference types that have reference semantics just like pointers in C/C++ (the main exceptions are value types: enums and structs).

But in this case just make `ProgramDat` `internal` and it can be accessed by other types as `Program.ProgramDat` as long as the other type is in the same assembly.

If you have significant state to share (and unless it is immutable that's an anti-pattern) wrap it in a reference type, instantiate in `Main` and pass the reference into the thread.

**NB.** the `ref` modify changes parameters from pass by value to pass by reference; this allows the called function to change the value of a variable in the called.

```
void PassByRef(ref int x) {
  x = 42;
}

void PassByValue(int x) {
  // This has no effect
  x = 84;
}

var Caller() {
  x = 1;
  Console.WriteLine(x); // Writes 1
  PassByRef(ref x);
  Console.WriteLine(x); // Writes 42
  PassByValue(x);
  Console.WriteLine(x); // Writes 42: no change by PassByValue
}
```